# Help on Themes. Unable to change color of attached section

Tags: theme

I just started learning blender yesterday. I was customizing the themes but I am unsure as to what section is the following (with the dark gray background and black text). I am unable to read my layer names clearly.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The *Dope Sheet > Channels* (`ThemeDopeSheet.channels`) option modifies the background for the [channel entries](https://docs.blender.org/manual/de/dev/editors/graph_editor/channels.html).

[image: Theme preferences]

The text for the unselected channels is defined by *Dope Sheet > Theme Space List > Source List Text* (`ThemeSpaceListGeneric.list_text`).